# remove shadow from ion-searchbar in ionic 3

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, searchbar

I need to remove the border from ion-search bar . I tried the following code in variable.scss but got no luck.I am pretty new in ionic so please tell me in details.

```
 .searchbar-input {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
        0 3px 1px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
        0 3px 1px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting a css property? You are stating you want to remove the border and/or shadow, right? Why don't you use box-shadow: none; border: none if you want to remove them?

Comment: I tried that too but it's not working so i think by putting a white shadow it might work but it's not working too

Comment: Without see the search bar exactly is hard to figure out. You are referring to this? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/

Comment: yes this is what i am using

Comment: Can you post the output of your browser?

Comment: how can i send image

Comment: You can't upload it online and share the link in your post or embed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is hard to figure out a solution without the output of your code, you might try this:

```
.searchbar-input {
    border: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked now !important is what i was looking for

Comment: @HemantRajpoot: Glad if I could help, don't forget to mark the reply as answer if it  fixed your problem. Thanks

Comment: I tried this solution and it doesn't work for ionic4, can you please help?

Comment: For ionic 4 (I suppose is for md - material design - android):

try:
.sc-ion-searchbar-md {box-shadow: none !important}

Place this in your scss file for seach bar component in <searchbar-input> scss definition.

Please let me know if it works to update the answer

Answer (score 6):

If it is ionic 4, try this:

```
.sc-ion-searchbar-md-h {
  --box-shadow: none !important
}
```

In the SCSS file of the component which uses the searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ionic 3, the solution that worked for me was put this code in the scss associate file:

```
  ion-searchbar {
    .searchbar-input-container {
      .searchbar-input {
        box-shadow: none;
      }
    }
  }
```