# How to remove ionic 4 ion-searchbar show?

Tags: ionic4

How to remove shadow from ionic 4 ion-search bar?
i already tried no-border no-shadow but didn't achieve what i want.

```html
<ion-searchbar
    no-border>
</ion-searchbar>
```

```css
ion-searchbar{
    --box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to force it through `!important`

```css
.searchbar-input {
    border: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028440/remove-shadow-from-ion-searchbar-in-ionic-3)